# Center aligning buttons text inside div dynamically?

Tags: html, css

Tried a lot of solutions I found, but nothing seems to work for me.

I want to center text inside button dynamiclly, no matter the width and height of the button, the text should always be in the center, I'm sure there's a good solution for this. I always find myself struggling with it.

```
<div class="gform_button">
    <input type="submit" class="gform_button" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

[image]

Tried almost everything, I don't understand why the following code doesn't work:

```
.gform_button{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If someone please can give me a good explanation of how it works and why the two above lines doesn't centering the text even thou it seems that this is their purpose. I always struggle with centering things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you put all the code? Only with this the text is in the middle.

Comment: just found that the button has a default paddings, maybe this causes the problem?

Comment: Maybe, if you could put more code, the help will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, text inside `input[type='submit']` should always be center-aligned (vertically/horizontally). Double-check your styles, maybe you broke the margin/padding of your div/input element.

Comment: It seems that my parent theme has some paddings that cause this to happen. But in general I always find myself struggle with centering things in css :/ Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="gform">
    <input type="submit" class="gform_button" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

css:

```
input.gform_button{ background-color:blue;color:white}
```

Also jsfiddle for you:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/bnhf5hg9/5/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.gform_button{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:3px;
}
</style>

<div>
    <input type="submit" class="gform_button" value="Submit" />
</div>
```